# Issue with mongodb user authentication

Tags: mongodb, grails

I am trying to connect from SERVER-1 to my mongo server which is running in some other sever SERVER-2
So my grails app is running in SERVER-1. So I have given external configuration like this.

```
grails {
    mongo {
        host = "<SERVER-2>-host"
        port = 27017
        username = "myapp"
        password = "myapp"
        databaseName = "myapp"
        options {
            autoConnectRetry = true
            connectTimeout = 3000
        }
    }
}
```

And in the SERVER-2 I've created myapp db and with the same user and credentials

```
use myapp
db.createUser( { "user" : "myapp",
                 "pwd": "myapp",
                 "roles" : [] },
               { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 } )
```

And am able to see the users list like below

```
> db.getUsers()
[
    {
        "_id" : "myapp.myapp",
        "user" : "myapp",
        "db" : "myapp",
        "roles" : [ ]
    }
]
```

Mongo configuration contains "noauth=true",
And from SERVER-1, I'm able to connect to SERVER-2 mongo using the below command

```
mongo SERVER-2-HOST:27017/myapp  -u myapp -p myapp
```

But when i try to connect from SERVER-1 grails application, its giving the below error

```
| Error Error executing script LoadVars: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [myapp], username = [myapp], password = [m***p]
```

My mongod.conf file

```
# mongod.conf

logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

logappend=true

fork=true

#port=27017

dbpath=/var/lib/mongo

pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
#bind_ip=127.0.0.1

# nojournal=true

#cpu=true

#noauth=false
auth=true
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Are you using MongoDB 3 and Grails 2.4.x or 2.5.x?

Comment: If yes, see my updated answer. That must be your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your MongoDB server is running and listening properly but not able to authenticate.

The first problem I'm seeing is that, you mentioned your Grails application is running on 1st server while your MongoDB server is on the 2nd, but the `host` in your `DataSource.groovy` configuration is configured to connect to the 1st host, not the 2nd. Is that just in the example or your code is really connecting to the 1st server (which is wrong)? Please verify it.

The second problem might be with the way you are adding the user to the database name `myapp`. Please follow these steps and try again after connecting:

1) Login to MongoDB instance on the 2nd host: `mongo`
2) Use your database `use myapp`
3) Verify that you don not have any user named `myapp` by running `db.dropUser("myapp")`
4) Now add the user:

```
db.createUser({
    user: "myapp",
    pwd: "myapp",
    roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
});
```

Now connect your Grails application.

**Update**

If you are using MongoDB 3.x and Grails 2.5.x or 2.4.x then this should be the problem of your authentication failure. I almost forgot to tell you this problem.

Grails somehow shipping the older version of Java driver i.e. `2.12.3` and to support MongoDB 3, we require minimum `2.13.x` of Java driver. Also, the 3.0 Java driver is not a required upgrade for MongoDB 3.0. The 2.13.0 release is the minimum required for full compatibility with MongoDB 3.0.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/releases/tag/r3.0.0

So, in your `BuildConfig.groovy` add this as `dependency`:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.13.1"
}
```

Also, if you are using Grails mongeez plugin, exclude the java driver from there:

```
compile (":mongeez:0.2.3") {
    excludes("mongo-java-driver")
}
```

I'll create a ticket for this in Grails. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes Shashank, Thanks for the reply. 
The URL was pointing to SERVER-2 itself(that was my typo mistake)
And I dropped the old user and I've created new user with the above command you mentioned.
And I'm able to connect to SERVER-2 from SERVER-1 command line, using below command
mongo SERVER-2-HOST:27017/myapp  -u myapp -p myapp

But still not able to connect to SERVER-2 from SERVER-1 grails application

Comment: Can you please paste your `mongod.conf` (probably in `/etc/mongod.conf`) if confortable

Comment: I added the config file please check

Comment: Can you please comment that `auth=true` for a while, restart the MongoDB instance and try to reconnect the Grails app?

Answer (score 0):

Creating database-specific authentic user:
1. Run mongod from cmd
2. Run mongo from cmd
3. use "your_db_name"
4.

```
db.createUser(
      {
        user: "anik",
        pwd: "password",
        roles: [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "your_db_name" } ]
      }
    )
```

Take note of the db name. Insert urs.
5. `mongo "your_db_name"  -u anik -p password`
6. Switch to your collections bson folder
7. `mongorestore -d ss "abc.bson"`

After Authentication you can connect to db using username password from your project properties file.

Comment: Hi @Istiak Morsalin, Thanks for the reply. As per your comment I missed only the role as "dbOwner". So I've given that too. So now still I'm not able to connect from the grails application.
In my mongodb config file I've commented out "bind_ip" config to enable all ports. Is that causing the issue?

Comment: You must specify the IP (199.21.114.XX), by running mongo 199.21.114.XX.

Otherwise, if you want it to listen on localhost as well, you should remove the bind_ip setting in your config file.

Update Check your firewall config. Since you're connecting to the external IP, it can be configured to block, even from the local box.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue with my setup.
Actually I was using grails mongo version 3.0.0
and I installed MongoDB 3.0.0. So according to this [grails mongo documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongodb/manual/guide/1.%20Introduction.html#1.2%20Release%20Notes), grails mongo 3.0.0 plugin supports only MongoDB 2.6. But I was using 3.0.0(upgraded version). 
Check this.
https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/557
So now MongoDB 3.0 doesn't support SCRAM-SHA-1 authSchema. So we should use some other techniques to authenticate our user.